# This query in codeigniter is not properly working. LIKE operator is not working properly... The codes in below

Tags: sql, codeigniter, sql-like

here in two condition, $data & $data1 are diifferent.

```
function f_report_by_year($data, $data1){
            $this->db->join('student', 'student.student_id = pay_log.student_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where('pay_log.timedate >=', $data.'-04-01');
            $this->db->where('pay_log.timedate <=', $data1.'-03-31');
            $this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MDF', 'before');
            $this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MEF', 'before');
            $this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MDD', 'before');
            $q = $this->db->get('pay_log');
            return $q->result_array();
        }
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or just unexpected results?

Answer (score 1):

Try This `or_group_start()`
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping

```
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->where('pay_log.timedate >=', $data.'-04-01');
$this->db->where('pay_log.timedate <=', $data1.'-03-31');
$this->db->group_end();
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MDF', 'before');
$this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MEF', 'before');
$this->db->or_like('pay_log.activity', 'MDD', 'before');
$this->db->group_end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that =>

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array(array(3, 6), 'live', 'Rick'));
```